# Qt requires to click twice to switch context menus among items

Tags: qt, contextmenu

I develop a tree view and implement context menus for its items. Right click an item, its context menu pops up. Right click an other item, the old context menu disappears but the new menu doesn't appear. Another right click is required to show the new context menu. Any way to make one right click works in this case? My code to generate the context menu is as below

```
void MyTreeView::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event) override
{
    if (Item* item = itemAt(event->pos())) {
        unique_ptr<QMenu> menu(item->createMenu(this));
        if (menu && !menu->isEmpty())
            menu->exec(event->globalPos());
    }
}
```

Comment: It always displays menu immediately for me on Windows. This behavior can be platform-dependent, and if it is, it probably follows common look-and-feel or guidelines for the platform, so that probably should not be changed. But you can try to move this implementation from `contextMenuEvent` to `mouseReleaseEvent` (the only change is to add checking which button has been released).

Comment: I am working on windows also. I build a small application and it doesn't need 2 clicks. I cannot figure out any reason that will require 2 clicks in my large application.